# How to get Java heap-dump from service installed with install4j?

Tags: install4j, heap-dump, memory-dump

install4j creates windows executable which loads JVM dll. Is there any way to force it to create a heap dump? VisualVM and other tools report it as unsupported JVM.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the JVM of a service does not run as the same user as VisualVM, so the attach API of the JRE does not work.

You can take an HPROF heap dump with [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html). In the quick attach dialog, select the "Show services" button and then click on the "Heap dump only" button at the bottom.